# Can a method calls it own class?

Tags: java

I'm working on a project where I use Foo which is class that's implemented with an interface, FooExpression, and a separate concrete class called Replacement.

Replacement class uses hashmap:

```
private Map<Foo, FooExpression> replacementMap;
```

Replacement class uses put method:

```
public Expression put(Foo foo, FooExpression exp) {
    return replacementMap.put(foo, exp);
}
```

The Replacement class has a method called get:

```
public FooExpression get(Foo foo) {
     return replacementMap.get(foo);
}
```

The Foo class has a method, applyReplacement:

```
@Override
public FooExpression applyReplacement(Replacement r) {
    Foo foo = new Foo(name);
    FooExpression e = r.get(foo);
    return e;
}
```

The Foo class uses an instance variable:

```
private String name;
```

The Foo class uses an equal and hashCode():

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Foo)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return name.equals(o);
    }
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode() + 41;
}
```

The FooExpression interface uses the applyReplacement method:

```
FooExpression applyReplacement(Replacement r);
```

Everytime I used applyReplacement method it returns null, simply because of the "new" instantiation.

I'm just wondering if there's a way to implement the Foo without erasing the existing value from the Replacement class? And I can't use generics for this one.

Comment: Does `Foo` implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` **correctly**?

Comment: Of course it'd return `null` every time if you never put anything into a map.

Comment: Are you looking for 'this'? As in r.get(this)?

Comment: @LinosaysReinstateMonica I'm sure I've added them correctly. I've updated the question.

Comment: @jay1984 is this really your equals method? if yes then there's your error. You're trying to compare `foo` (I assume a `String`) to `o` which is an instance of `Foo`. You probably meant to do this: `return o instanceof Foo && foo.equals(((Foo) o).foo);` (I compacted your if-else into a single short circuiting operation)

Comment: @LinosaysReinstateMonica Thank you for this! It actually does get the foo value correctly.

Comment: I noticed that your `put` method works with a value called `substitutionMap` instead or `replacementMap`... I don't know if this is just the pseudo-code example though or if it's also like that in the actual code?

Comment: Does the Foo class really contain an *instance field* named `foo`?  Regardless, it appears your hashCode method is not consistent with the equals method:  one compares `foo` while the other compares `name`.  They should be based on the same fields.

Comment: @VGR Noted made that change.

Comment: @SylarBenes It's a typo, sorry. Made that change.

Comment: Your mthod `applyReplacement` has the @Override annotation. What superclass does it override the method of? And does this superclass have a replacementMap property?

Comment: Thank you.  Now, I assume `name` is declared as a String, which means it will *never* be equal to an instance of Foo.  Perhaps you meant `return name.equals(((Foo) o).name);`?

Comment: @VGR I've made the changes, thank you.

Comment: @SylarBenes It's overriding the interface method of FooExpression. I've updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `equals()` method is wrongly implemented, currently it checks:

- if `o instanceof Foo`
- and if `name.equals(o)`

But `o` is in this case an instance of `Foo`. Your `name` though is an instance of `String`. This will never return `true` as a `String` will ***never*** be equal to a `Foo`.

You have to change your equals method accordingly:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof Foo)) {
        return false;
    }
    Foo foo = (Foo) o;
    return name.equals(foo.name);
}
```

Which can also be simplified to:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Foo && name.equals(((Foo) o).name);
}
```